# Merge two dataframes by respecting the values in specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have two such data frames:

df1:

```
                     DayYear_Count      Time
0                                           
2018-03-26 00:00:00             84  00:00:00
2018-03-26 01:00:00             84  01:00:00
2018-03-26 02:00:00             84  02:00:00
2018-03-26 03:00:00             84  03:00:00
2018-03-26 04:00:00             84  04:00:00
```

df2:

```
       Time       Temp  DayYear_Count
0      00:00:00   6.065167             84
1      01:00:00   5.692167             84
2      02:00:00   5.151917             84
3      03:00:00   4.636500             84
4      04:00:00   4.277417             84
```

I want to merge the two data frames into a single data frame in which the 'Time' and 'DayYear_Count' columns coincide. So I would only have the values in the 'Temp' column at those positions. Something like:

```
                   DayYear_Count      Time     Temp  
0                                           
2018-03-26 00:00:00             84  00:00:00   6.065
2018-03-26 01:00:00             84  01:00:00   3.055
2018-03-26 02:00:00             84  02:00:00   "Nan"
```

I have entered random values to give the idea.

Comment: Why is `Nan` forlast value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use left join with [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and for avoid `MultiIndex` convert it to column `0`:

```
df1['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Time']).dt.time
df2['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Time']).dt.time

df1['DayYear_Count'] = df1['DayYear_Count'].astype(int)
df2['DayYear_Count'] = df2['DayYear_Count'].astype(int)

df = df1.reset_index().merge(df2, on=['DayYear_Count','Time'], how='left').set_index(0)
```

Comment: When I use it, I obtain NaT in the index. Why?

Comment: @SimonePanico - Are same dtypes? Add to answer for convert both columns to times and `DayYear_Count` to numeric if necessary.

Comment: It solved everything. Thank you!